# Código na camada de negócio do depois de gravar dos funcionários (V10)

Tags: c#

Pretendo colocar código no evento depois de gravar da camada de negócio dos motores do ERP primavera V10, para efetuar algumas ações nos funcionários independentemente da origem da alteração dos dados.
No entanto, o código abaixo não está a ser executado. É preciso configurar mais alguma coisa?
Tenho outro código no evento depois de gravar dos funcionários nos editores que está a funcionar normalmente.

```
public class ApiRhpBSFuncionarios : RhpBSFuncionarios
{
    public override void DepoisDeGravar(RhpBEFuncionario ObjBEFuncionario, ExtensibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        base.DepoisDeGravar(ObjBEFuncionario, e);

        /*
        código diverso
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde,

É necessário colocar este código depois do AbreEmpresaTrabalho:

```
// Use this service to trigger the API events.
ExtensibilityService service = new ExtensibilityService();

service.Initialize(_BSO);

// Check if service is operational
if (service.IsOperational)
{
    // Inshore that all extensions are loaded.
    service.LoadExtensions();
}
```

Para isto é necessário também fazer os seguinte using:

```
using Primavera.Extensibility.Engine;
```

Referenciando as seguintes dlls:

```
Primavera.Extensibility.Engine.dll
Primavera.Extensibility.Patterns.dll
```

Comment: Boa tarde Daniel,

Penso que esta solução não se aplique. O código que indiquei está a correr no ERP V10, tal como se fosse o VBA da V9. Não é uma aplicação externa, pelo que penso não ser necessário qualquer AbreEmpresaTrabalho.
Por herdar da classe RhpBSFuncionarios já tem acesso ao BSO e PSO.

Answer (score -3):

Olá

Essse tipo de eventos não estão ainda disponiveis para esse modulo, pelo menos para já. Pelo que consegui saber junto o produtor trata-se de uma limitação sem uma data de resolução.